# formatting json returned from ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

Hi I have an ajax call which returns a json string which consists of -

```
"{"d":
    [
        {"path":"/","e_type":"d ","text":"/"},
        {"path":"//SQL","e_type":"d ","text":"//SQL"},
        {"path":"//SQL/SourceClips","e_type":"d ","text":"//SQL/SourceClips"},
        {"path":"//SQL/SourceClips/kjpDNxHD145_MC403.mov","e_type":"f ", "text":"//SQL/SourceClips/kjpDNxHD145_MC403.mov"}
    ]
 }"
```

I am trying to format this so there are 3 objects and one object inside the 3rd object. I want to use a loop so i can reuse this for any data I return.

Currently that is fine as far as printing each item on separate lines but i am trying to nest the last item into the third item.

Any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: Server side ? If yes, which language used ?

Comment: Your question is not clear. Still, some remarks: (1) I don't know how you are wrapping things, but if you are using `"` as a delimiter of the contents, you may wish to use `'` as the wrapping character of the JSON. (2) if you want the 4th element to be inside the 3rd, just add a field within the 3rd whose value is the current value of the 4th. (3) when you say **print**, what do you mean?

Comment: Hi I am sorry i am using Client side and using javascript / Jquery.

Comment: Hi When i said print i just meant taht i did a console.oog and passed the json in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var parsed_data = JSON.parse(ajax_data);
```